# SORT formula is pulling in null cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that uses the following formulas

To merge data an importrange and another sheet (column J):

```
=iferror(vlookup(D2,List_of_Things!A:N,13,false),"")
```

To sort that data based on the vlookup (=importrange record's key):

```
=SORT(FILTER(B:J,NOT(ISBLANK(J:J)),NOT(ISBLANK(D:D))),9,FALSE)
```

Where J has a numeric value, the data is sorted but it's pulling a bunch of null values before it gets to the populated numbers in J.

How do I adjust the =importrange results so that I can have a numerically-sorted (column J) output with the merged data?

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with some dummy data - its difficult to visualize what is actually happening in your sheet without seeing an example - you can use pretend data - but it would yield a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
=iferror(vlookup(D2,List_of_Things!A:N,13,false),"")
```

use

```
=iferror(vlookup(D2,List_of_Things!A:N,13,false),)
```

This because an empty text (`""`) is not the same as blank.

Alternatively, instead of using ISBLANK  use LEN. This because the length of a blank cell and a cell containing an empty text is 0.

Related

- [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101171/88163) to [Create a list of categories from a 2D array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101148/88163)
- [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79577/88163) to [How Do I Combine Columns In Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45065/88163)